# Custom field widget: hook_field_is_empty()

Tags: entities

I'm creating a custom module that has implemented these hooks:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_hook_info() {
  return array(
    'CUSTOM_field' => array(
      'label' => t('Custom Text Area'),
      'field_types' => array('text_long'),
      'behaviors' => array(
        'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
        'default value' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  switch($instance['widget']['type']) {
    case 'CUSTOM_field':
      $element['MYFIELD_field'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#attributes' => array('id' => 'MYFIELD', 'rows' => '5', 'cols' => '3'),
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]) ? $items[$delta] : '',
      );
      break;
  }
  return array('value' => $element);
}
```

All it is supposed to do is provide a custom widget to the Long Text field type that enables some custom functionality. My custom widget appears in manage fields and I can enable it and use it on a node edit form. However, when I save the node with text in the field, <strike>nothing saves to the database</strike> the data saves to the database, but doesn't display in the field when the node is edited again.

After some searching, I found some posts that said hook_field_is_empty() is mandatory and is a common problem for values not saving. I attempted to implement the hook exactly as the API said:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_is_empty().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  if (empty($item['value']) && (string) $item['value'] !== '0') {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

This immediately started throwing an error in Drupal:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1573 of /includes/bootstrap.inc).

So I looked around some more on here and Google and changed the hook based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433039/drupal-field-widget-not-saving-submitted-data):

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_is_empty().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  if ($field['type'] == 'text_long') {
    if (empty($item[$field['type']]['CUSTOM_field'])) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

This returns the same error and it also doesn't <strike>save the value of the field into the database</strike> display the field data from the database. Do I have to create a custom field with a MYMODULE.install and the appropriate hooks, or can I just use an existing field type like I'm doing. Why is the data not <strike>saving to</strike> pulling from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't working because I have WYSIWYG enabled. Apparently this means my values for textareas get passed as value/type arrays instead of strings. Changing default_value accordingly works:

```
'#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['value']) ? $items[$delta]['value'] : '',
```

This change solved my problems. I also removed the hook_field_is_empty() and haven't noticed any problems using the widget. Perhaps it's only mandatory for custom field types.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change your default values to `variable_get('yourmodule_variable')` so that it displays the value that was saved previously.