# Custom Drupal field widget causing check_plain() error

Tags: entities

I'm working on a custom field widget for Drupal 7. Everything appears to be working correct, but now I'm getting this error:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1565 includes\bootstrap.inc)

My .module hooks:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_hook_info() {
  return array(
    'CUSTOM_field' => array(
      'label' => t('Custom Text Area'),
      'field_types' => array('text_long'),
      'behaviors' => array(
        'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
        'default value' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  switch($instance['widget']['type']) {
    case 'CUSTOM_field':
      $element['text_long'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#attributes' => array('id' => 'MYFIELD', 'rows' => '5', 'cols' => '3'),
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['value']) ? $items[$delta]['value'] : '',
      );
      break;
  }
  return array('value' => $element);
}
```

My guess is that it's something in the way Drupal is attempting to validate my value with check_plain(), but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: This link may you https://www.drupal.org/node/1019252.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [hook description](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form/7), $items is an "**Array** of default values for this field."  You are trying to look in an **array of arrays** in your default value.

You need to change this line:

```
    '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['value']) ? $items[$delta]['value'] : '',
```

to look in the $items array, rather than the $items[$delta] array (which doesn't exist) by removing ['value'], like this:

```
    '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]) ? $items[$delta] : '',
```

Comment: I initially had my default value as you recommend, but when I did, the value in the database was not being loaded into the field on node/edit. See my question about that issue here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128552/custom-field-widget-hook-field-is-empty/128570#128570